# PowerShell Script to display service status and if stopped rename folder

Tags: powershell

What am I doing wrong?  It will not rename folder if service status is stopped?

```
$computers =("GT08544","GT08545")
$arrService = Get-Service -Name Spooler
Get-Service -ComputerName $computers Spooler | Select Displayname, Status
if ($arrService.Status -eq 'running')
{
Exit
}
If ($arrServie.Status -eq 'stopped')
{
Rename-Item \\GT08324\c$\Ken Ken.$(Get-Date -format "yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss") -Force
}
(Write-Host "Renaming completed successfully")
```

Comment: Is this a direct copy of your script? First thing I notice is in this line `If ($arrServie.Status -eq 'stopped')` , `$arrServie` is mispelled. Do you get an error?

Comment: Corrected spelling and it still just gives DisplayName and Status...no errors

Comment: Is server you are running it froms spooler service running? I tested and it works fine. If it is running, it wont do anything. Was the intention to rename that folder if the spooler service is stopped on one of the remote servers?

Comment: Yes, the intent is to have the folder renamed if status of service is stopped, exit script if running

Comment: on the local computer or the computers defined in `$computers` ? As it stands now, it only looks at the local service.

Comment: I am checking the spooler service on the items defined in $computers.....

Comment: you are printing their status, but that is all. The if statements are evaluating the local machines spooler status

Answer (score 0):

The following will allow you to do what you want to do. This code runs a service check on each one of the servers individually. Then it renames that directory if it exists. A test-path check is done beforehand incase they are both stopped, the second iteration will not error out if the folder has already been renamed.

```
$computers =("GT08544","GT08545")

foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock 
    {
        $arrService = Get-Service -Name Spooler
        Write-Host "Spooler Service is $arrService.Status on $computer" 

        if ($arrService.Status -eq "Running")
        {
            Write-host "Running. No Action being taken."
        }
        if ($arrService.Status -eq "Stopped")
        {
            if (Test-Path -Path "\\GT08324\c$\Ken")
            {
                Rename-Item \\GT08324\c$\Ken Ken.$(Get-Date -format "yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss") -Force
            }
            else
            {
                Write-host "The path does not exist or has already been renamed"
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Edit to address comments below. This version runs the service check on each Server. If the service is stopped, it adds to the variable $count. At the end, if the $count variable is 2 (means both servers have a stopped spooler service, then it will rename the folder only if this condition is met. Should just be able to copy/paste into powershell ise or a script with no edits.

```
$computer1 = "GT08544"
$computer2 = "GT08545"

$serviceCount1 = ""
$serviceCount2 = ""

$Response = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer1     {

        $arrService = Get-Service -Name Spooler
        $count=0

        if ($arrService.Status -eq "Running")
        {
            Write-host "$Using:computer1 - Running. No Action being taken."
        }
        if ($arrService.Status -eq "Stopped")
        {
            Write-Host "$Using:computer1 - Service is Stopped. Increasing Service count by 1."
            $count++
            Write-Host $count
        }
        Return @{serviceCount1 = $count}
   }

$Response.GetEnumerator() | % { Set-Variable $_.Key -Value $_.Value}


$Response2 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer2     {

        $arrService = Get-Service -Name Spooler
        $count=0

        if ($arrService.Status -eq "Running")
        {
            Write-host "$Using:computer2 - Running. No Action being taken."
        }
        if ($arrService.Status -eq "Stopped")
        {
            Write-Host "$Using:computer2 - Service is Stopped. Increasing Service count by 1."
            $count++
            Write-Host $count
        }
        Return @{serviceCount2 = $count}
   }

$Response2.GetEnumerator() | % { Set-Variable $_.Key -Value $_.Value}

$totalStoppedServices = $serviceCount1 + $serviceCount2
Write-Host "Total Stopped Services: $totalStoppedServices"

if($totalStoppedServices = 2){
    if(test-path -Path "\\GT08324\c$\Ken"){
        Rename-Item \\GT08324\c$\Ken Ken.$(Get-Date -format "yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss") -Force
        }
    }
    else{
    Write-host "Service is running on one or more servers. No Action."
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Narzard!  I do have one question, what happens if on one server the service is stopped and the other is running?  How could I get a check that will only rename folder if both services are stopped?

Comment: Also, getting and error with the Invoke-Command...missing an argument for parameter 'ScriptBlock'.  Specify a parameter of type 'System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock' and try again....Thank you so much helping me out, I really appreciate the guidance!

Comment: @Ken added a new script as an edit. This version should do all the things that you want. It will only rename the folder if both spooler services are stopped.

Comment: Thank you again for all of your help with this...it is much appreciated!!